# Explanation of equation from DeepLearning Book

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

I have been reading Deep Learning from Goodfellow et al

In chapter 6, Deep Feedforward networks, in choosing the mapping for ϕ, they've used the equation $y=f(x;θ,w)=ϕ(x;θ)^Tw$. I was wondering why are there two parameters. Does it mean $θ$ is used to learn the function $ϕ$ and not the function $f$. Also is the parameter $θ$ necessary? Can't the function be learned only using $w$.

Comment: Please provide additional context for your question. Where do these equations appear? Are they numbered equations? (If so, what are the numbers?) Could you directly quote the context in which these equations appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a typo in the formulation. It's actually the [following](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) (Page 166):
$$y=f(x;\theta,w)=\phi(x;\theta)^Tw$$
It means that neural nets learn a function of the data, where it also can be represented as a linear function of a nonlinear transformation of the data. $w$ are the weights of the last layer (output layer) of the feedforward neural network, such that when multiplied with the hidden layers' outputs it gives $f$. So, by learning $\phi$ and $w$, we learn $f$.

If there was only $w$, it would mean no hidden layers, and the output would equal to $x^Tw$, i.e. a linear model. Instead, we use hidden layer(s) and transform our data to $\phi(x)$ parameterised by $\theta$, i.e. $\phi(x;\theta)$, and then multiply the transformed features with output layer's weights.

Comment: Formula corrected. So does it mean that $\theta$ is the parameter for hidden layers and $w$ for output layer?

Comment: yes, it is correct.